# Saving value from JComboBox in custom TreeCellEditor

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I've got a `JTree` with a custom `TreeModel` and a custom `TreeCellEditor` displaying (for now) a `JComboBox` through the `getTreeCellEditorComponent()` override. The tree is displayed properly, with the nodes going into edit mode and displaying the `JComboBox` when I click on them.

Whenever I edit a node, changing the value from the dropdown, and then proceed to select another node from the three, I can see the `TreeCellEditor`'s `cancelCellEditing()` being triggered.

What's the "correct" way to **stop** editing in stead of cancelling it, thus (hopefully?) making sure the model's `valueForPathChanged()` get's triggered?

Comment: nobody knows how your `AbstractTreeModel` works, if notified all events correctly, but in the 90pct is `JTrees` events very similair (different names of methods) to the `JTables` events, search for `start / stop / cancelEdit` for `TableCellEditor`

Comment: Sorry, so many new terms for me here I get a little confused. I forgot `AbstractTreeModel` was just a class of my own implementing `TreeModel` plus some other (irrelevant) stuff. I updated the question.

I found a solution, but thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation in the source code I found the answer inside the JTree class:

Setting `JTree#setInvokesStopCellEditing(true)` means editing is stopped in stead of cancelled  whenever I change focus from one node to another. This also means my `TreeModel#valueForPathChanged()` gets called.